# For Loop not working as expected in Beanshell scripting Jmeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter, beanshell

Below is my code, where I am trying to loop through set of Status's and break if Status is equal N. And Save EpisodeId at same index. (using Javascript in beanshell postprocessor)

```
var i;
var count = vars.get("AuthStatus_matchNr");
var EpisodeID;

log.info("Count of Status:"+count)

for(i=0;i<=count;i++){
    var AuthStatus_i;
    AuthStatus_i = vars.get("AuthStatus_"+i);
    log.info("Auth:"+AuthStatus_i);
    if (AuthStatus_i == "N"){
    EpisodeID = vars.get("corr_EpisodeID_"+i);
    break;
    }
else{
    i++;
    }
}
log.info("EpisodeID:"+EpisodeID)
vars.put("EpisodeID",EpisodeID);
```

But my loop is not working as expected. Loop runs for 2 iteration and breaks before finding N status. Below is the Log response

```
Capture 'N' Status EpisodeID: Count of Status:3
Capture 'N' Status EpisodeID: Auth:null
Capture 'N' Status EpisodeID: Auth:A
Capture 'N' Status EpisodeID: EpisodeID:undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove this bit:

```
else {
        i++;
    }
```

because you're already doing the increment in for loop.

Also be aware that according to JMeter Best Practices you [should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating.

More information: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Answer (score 0):

I see where the issue is. In JavaScript, arrays and lists are zero-based, which means the index starts from 0, and the last index is count - 1. Therefore, you need to modify the condition i <= count to i < count in order to iterate over all the elements in the AuthStatus array.

So correct way to do it would be like this:

```
var i;
var count = vars.get("AuthStatus_matchNr");
var EpisodeID;

log.info("Count of Status: " + count);

for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var AuthStatus_i = vars.get("AuthStatus_" + i);
    log.info("Auth: " + AuthStatus_i);

    if (AuthStatus_i === "N") {
        EpisodeID = vars.get("corr_EpisodeID_" + i);
        break;
    }
}

log.info("EpisodeID: " + EpisodeID);
vars.put("EpisodeID", EpisodeID);
```

Now basically the loop will iterate through all the elements until it finds the "N" status and assigns the corresponding EpisodeID.